# Proprietary development process

Tags: terminology, paradigms

Is there a term specific to development that describes a company that has developed its own processes for development?  More specifically, poor development practices, management, processes and QA testing that is also difficult to learn.  Proprietary processes that do not carry over to other work environments.

Sometimes even subjective ideas become so ingrained they are viewed as true or false.

Comment: Hmm, something like "in house"?

Comment: @marto - Yes, along those lines but with a negative connotation.

Comment: "non-out-house"? That gives a vague association with "crap"

Comment: This should probably be on progammers, or english language and usage, but almost certainly not here.

Comment: "terrible in house processes" :P

Comment: @Tom - Yes, I had trouble deciding if it should land on one of those sites.  I chose SO because if the term already exists then there is a specific and non-subjective answer.  But, if the term is just "crap" or some general negative adjective then English SE is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your purpose is but I would go for a sentance rather than a single word, something like,

> opaque development practices that result from a management perfunctory
>   to all but its commercial secrets.  Less than the sum of its parts.

A little less strong:

> opaque development practices that are encouraged by a management that prioritizes novelty over practical expediency.

Comment: +1 Thats what I am getting at.  I am looking for a way to describe this type of an environment to a 3rd party in a concise and non-offensive manner.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey oh, I think mine might be a little too strong - I will tone it down.